# Replace current table data with result from querying the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that does not have any index or primary key in my MySQL database. I cannot change the schema of the table (it is not "my" table). As the table stores data that arrives in intervals, there can be (are) duplicates.

For example:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| first_seen   | last_seen    | type   | name     | hitcnt   | data    |
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| 15:12:02     | 16:02:32     | 5      | foo      | 3        | difank  |
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| 19:52:23     | 22:06:20     | 5      | foo      | 4        | difank  |
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Now I would like to "reduce" this to:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| first_seen   | last_seen    | type   | name     | hitcnt   | data    |
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| 15:12:02     | 22:06:20     | 5      | foo      | 7        | difank  |
+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
```

And I would like to do this "in situ" (i.e. in place) if possible.

Using `GROUP BY`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, etc. I can write a query that returns exactly what I want to end up with:

```
SELECT
  MIN(first_seen),
  MAX(last_seen),
  type,
  name,
  SUM(hitcnt) as hit,
  data
FROM <table>
GROUP BY type, name, data
ORDER BY hit desc, type;
```

The question is: how can I **replace** the existing data (efficiently) with the result of that query?

- Do I have to use a temporary table (i.e. move the data to a temporary table, truncate the existing table and `SELECT INTO` from the temporary table)?

  - Can I do this in a transaction (to prevent data loss if something goes wrong)?
- Are there other (better?) options than a temporary table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
INSERT INTO table_name (column1.....)
SELECT
  MIN(first_seen),
  MAX(last_seen),
  type,
  name,
  SUM(hitcnt) as hit,
  data
FROM <table>
GROUP BY type, name, data
ORDER BY hit desc, type;
```

Make sure number of columns of insert and select staement matches.

Comment: If `<table> == table_name` this would not work, right? The data will be gone by the time the `SELECT` is run, no? Or does this work when wrapped in a transaction?

Comment: Sorry for that answer, I understood your question now.
create another table
insert data into it, drop original table,rename table with original name.
lengthy method but always works

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following approach:

`CREATE TABLE tmp_table IF NOT EXISTS AS (SELECT ...);`

then move the "new" table into place using `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME ...;`

followed by a `DROP TABLE ...;` for the old/original table.

That seems to work.